# onRequestPermissionsResult error in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions

I need to ask the  user for permission to read and write on the SD card for android API +23.

I have arlready made my the part of asking the user for permission  and showing the dialog box.

The problem is that I'm unable to get the Premmission result.

I have this code:

```
@SuppressLint("Override")
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }
```

But I get always this error:

The method onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) is undefined for the type Activity

or

The method onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) is undefined for the type Fragment

How can I solve this errr?

Comment: what your targetSDK ?

Comment: Hi, mi min sdk is 16 and my target idk is 24

Comment: And my android SDK is completely updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first error, set your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 or higher.

For your second error, set your `compileSdkVersion` to 24 and use the latest version of the Android Support libraries.

Comment: Hi, but mi target SDK version is already 24. Or is it not the same?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues: "Or is it not the same?" -- no, it is not the same. `targetSdkVersion` is not `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues: Your `compileSdkVersion` is in the same `build.gradle` file as your `targetSdkVersion`, assuming that you are using Android Studio.

Comment: No i'm using eclipse like it says in the title of my question   :)

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues: Official support for Android development on Eclipse ended nine months ago. AFAIK, you cannot use modern versions of the Android support libraries with Eclipse, unless Eclipse gained support for AAR libraries somewhere along the line. I have not used Eclipse in ~2 years. The `compileSdkVersion` used to be in Project > Properties > Android.